# Error when using Laravel 5.4 Seeder Function

Tags: laravel

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, instance of
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given

I am planning to generate Fake date for user with profile. I have two model: User & Profile. I have done the relationship with each others. But when i execute it and the problems came. Above is the error when i running Seeder.

This is the class that found bug.

```
public function run()
{
    factory(App\User::class, 40)->create()->each(
        function($user) {
            $user->profile()->save(
                factory(App\Profile::class, 1)->make()
            );
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using Laravel 5.4.

The has been a modification in the factory() helper method. From the docs:

> The factory Helper
>   Calling factory(User::class, 1)->make() or factory(User::class, 1)->create() will now return a collection with one item. Previously, this would return a single model. This method will only return a single model if the amount is not supplied.

[Laravel 5.3 to 5.4 updgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade#upgrade-5.4.0)

That means that you should remove the 1 from your factory() call.

```
public function run(){
factory(App\User::class, 40)->create()->each(
    function($user) {
        $user->profile()->save(
            factory(App\Profile::class)->make()
        );
    }
);}
```

Edit 1: You have to change this line:

```
factory(App\Profile::class, 1)->make()
```

To this

```
factory(App\Profile::class)->make()
```

Comment: Thank for reply. Yes i am using laravel 5.4. Can you specific what exactly should be remove? Because i am beginner, not sure how it work.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the relation `$user->profile()` by calling the method, will return the related models as a `Collection`. You can do `$user->profile()->first()` to get a single result of type `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` or just `$user->profile` without the `()`.